# Pass value from one activity to another

Tags: android

I want to pass value from one activity to another activity.

`A -> B ->A` where A is the main activity. This code is working from `B->A` but not in `A->B`

this is my code for Activity A

```
class ChangeTextStyleTouchListener implements OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
   int request_code = 101;

        Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(context, ColorPickerActivity.class);

         intent.putExtra("colorCode", addText.getTextColors());
         intent.putExtra("fontSize", addText.getTextSize());

         startActivityForResult(intent,request_code);        }
}
```

and this is my code for activity B

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_picker);


    findViewById(R.id.btnAddSize).setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) new addTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.btnMinusSize).setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) new minusTouchListener());

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        int color = extras.getInt("colorCode");
        colorPicker.setColor(color);

        int size = extras.getInt("fontSize");
        colorPicker.setSize(size);
    }
}
```

my `extras` is null.

Comment: why you have 2 'onCreate()' in activity B?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my code

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
**Class A**
call B with pass extra        
Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(context, B.class);
intent.putExtra("colorCode", addText.getTextColors());
intent.putExtra("fontSize", addText.getTextSize());
startActivityForResult(intent,request_code);

result from B
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode==request_code){
                int color = data.getIntExtra("colorCode", 0);
                colorPicker.setColor(color);
                int size = data.getIntExtra("fontSize", 0);
                colorPicker.setSize(size);
            }
        }
}

**Class B**
getting extra from A
int color = getIntent().getIntExtra("colorCode",0);
colorPicker.setColor(color);
int size = getIntent().getIntExtra("fontSize",0);
colorPicker.setSize(size);

pass result to A
Intent intent = new Intent(context,A.class);
intent.putExtra("colorCode", addText.getTextColors());
intent.putExtra("fontSize", addText.getTextSize());
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
finish();
```

Comment: I Got this error. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.poc/com.example.poc.ColorPickerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there with your code. You are starting the activity `B` for result.. that means if you press back from `B` you'll get the result in activity `A`. The only thing missing here is you are returning nothing. You need to `setResult()` in activity `B` and set extras as to what you want to return. Also the result you are returning from `B` would be available in `onActivityResult()` method in `A`.. So be sure to override it according to your requirement.